# How can i array multiple objects properly?

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to array multiple objects by grouping the objects with a plane, setting the instance to face, and then using the array modifier to replicate the shapes, but it isn't working properly.

[image]

I have parented the ball to an empty that also controls the curve, so when I move the empty, the ball along with the curve moves with it. When I tried to use the instance array method with this, only the stem of the dandelion plant rotated, and the dandelion ball rotated on its own axis when it should be moving with the empty stem. Also, the empty space didn't move either.

[image]

This is how i want it to be.

Here is the .blend file if it helps:
https://we.tl/t-eLlCJNkAgF

Comment: Hello could you please show a drawing of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @moonboots Hi, I would like the result to resemble the second image, where there are four stems, each with its own ball. I used a hook to control the curve and also to manage the position of the ball. So, when I move the empty hook, it adjusts both the curve and the ball. It functions correctly when it is singular, but when I attempt to replicate the shape using an array, the ball doesn't move with the stick. In conclusion, I want to have one stick (curve) and ball that I can manipulate using the empty, and the other three repeated objects will follow suit.

Comment: maybe to replicate the balls, use Alt D, then hook the tip of the curve to the balls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable with drivers but you can use constraints: Create your first ball, hook the tip of the curve, duplicate the ball with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (if they need to share the same mesh), give it a *Transformation* constraint and a *Rotation* constraint with the first ball as *Target*, put it at the tip of another curve and hook the curve, duplicate this ball and again hook the curve. When you move the first ball the other ones should follow:

[image]

Here is how the *Transformation* constraints look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! That's what i was looking for.